# Hide part of activity_main.xml if keyboard is open (Android)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, keyboard

I have the following **activity_main.xml** shown at bottom. There, a `CoordinatorLayout` and two `LinearLayouts` occur. The first LinearLayout1 has an `EditText` to input some text, with a button to send it. The second one has two other buttons.

If i click into the `EditText`, the keyboard shows up and makes everything in LinearLayout2 barely visible. So, i want to hide both buttons in last layout when keyboard is open.

I already found out to use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` may be the trick, but only in connection with activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I just want to use this inner the second linear layout. Already tried to use it there, but with no success.

In addition, i what to handle this in my xml and keep my MainActivity-code clean. Any possibilities for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <EditText/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button_send"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had same issue in past so we have put some observable on full layout object
try this and let me know

```
/*Hide button when keyboard is open*/
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

        int heightDiff = view.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

        if (heightDiff > 244) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
            //ok now we know the keyboard is up...
            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        } else {
            //ok now we know the keyboard is down...
            buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Its a shame Android provides no better solution, but yours is a nice workaround. Thanks.