# How to validate virtual keyboard visibility?

Tags: android

I want to show a button when the virtual keyboard is open and hide this button if the virtual keyboard visibility is off.But I could not find any listeners to perform this activity.
Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](https://felhr85.net/2014/05/04/catch-soft-keyboard-showhidden-events-in-android/), you'll need to instantiate the `SoftkeyBoard` and add a listener.

```
/*
Somewhere else in your code
*/

RelativeLayout mainLayout = findViewById(R.layout.main_layout); // You must use your root layout
InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);     

/*
Instantiate and pass a callback
*/

SoftKeyboard softKeyboard;
softKeyboard = new SoftKeyboard(mainLayout, im);
softKeyboard.setSoftKeyboardCallback(new SoftKeyboard.SoftKeyboardChanged()
{
 @Override  
  public void onSoftKeyboardHide()   
  {
        // Code here  
  }  

  @Override 
   public void onSoftKeyboardShow()  
   { 
       // Code here 
   }   
});     

/*
Open or close the soft keyboard programatically
*/

softKeyboard.openSoftKeyboard();
softKeyboard.closeSoftKeyboard();


/*
SoftKeyboard can catch keyboard events when an EditText gains focus and keyboard appears
*/


/* Prevent memory leaks:
*/

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{  
  super.onDestroy(); 
   softKeyboard.unRegisterSoftKeyboardCallback();
}
```

In his post, you will also find more information about bug fixes and possible problems.

Answer (score 0):

add onGlobalLayoutListener to your parent view of activity/fragment and make your button visibility accordingly

```
final View parentView= findViewById(R.id.myrootview);  
       parentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int heightDiff = root.getRootView().getHeight() - root.getHeight();

            Rect rectgle= new Rect();
            Window window= getWindow();
            window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectgle);
            int contentViewTop= 
                window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();

            if(heightDiff <= contentViewTop){
                //Soft KeyBoard Hidden---button visible

            }else{
                //Soft KeyBoard Shown---button hide
            }


         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct event for keyboard open and close. but you can create observer on your full layout and then display buttons or whatever you want to do. 
For Observer code check this - [Hide part of activity_main.xml if keyboard is open (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267425/hide-part-of-activity-main-xml-if-keyboard-is-open-android/35267926#35267926)