# Hide BottomNavigationView when Keyboard opens

Tags: android

I have a **MainActivity** that has a **android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView** and a **FrameLayout** init:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.virascience.app.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/actionBarSize"
        tools:context="com.virascience.app.MainActivity">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now when I clicked on **SearchView** in one of my fragments, **BottomNavigationView** goes up with the keyboard.

I tried this code in **AndroidManifest.xml** but not working for me:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

How can I hide **BottomNavigationView** when keyboard opens?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216749/softkeyboard-open-and-close-listener-in-an-activity-in-android) post might help you answer. You can set your view based on visibility of your keyboard

Comment: You can check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35267926/2128166