# How to hide bottom navigation bar when keyboard is open in android app development?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-bottom-nav-view

I'm creating android app, in that there is bottom navigation bar like youtube and other social media. And there is one textbox in my application, so when i type on textbox keyboard is open and bottom navigation bar is reside over my keyboard. So how can i hide bottom navigation bar when i start typing.

Parent layout of app is Linearlayout.

And adjustPan will not work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267425/hide-part-of-activity-main-xml-if-keyboard-is-open-android/35267926#35267926

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation

Comment: You are talking about "back", "home" and "recents" buttons here. The question is about BottomNavigationBar